# How to install OpenSSH 8.7 or later on 20.04.6 LTS

Tags: apt, server, package-management, upgrade, ssh

I need to upgrade the version of OpenSSH on my Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS to OpenSSH 8.7 or later.
After running this:

```
sudo apt upgrade 
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

It returns;

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
openssh-server is already the newest version (1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.11).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Running

```
ssh -V
```

Returns

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.11, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

How do I upgrade it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: No that does not help.  I understand why but I need to install that version for a security audit.  I want to know how to do it

Comment: Your security audit is suspect. If they can point to a CVE, you can point to a mitigation at https://security.ubuntu.com for your current (fully patched) version of openSSH. Patching is a decades-old and fully-accepted method of mitigation. Failure of an audit to include patching is a big red flag suggesting an incomptent auditor and that your organization is wasting its money.

Comment: An alternate mitigation would be to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04.  Some auditors don't like that answer either.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone looking at this, I just updated Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1344955)